# Why can't add child to the node created by appendNode()?

Tags: xml, groovy

I want to create a xml like this:

```
<root>
  <level1>
    <levl2/>
  </level1>
</root>
```

Here is my groovy code:

```
def root="<root/>"
def l1 = "<level1/>"
def l2 = "<level2/>"

def dom = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(root)
dom.appendNode(new XmlSlurper().parseText(l1))
dom.level1.appendNode(new XmlSlurper().parseText(l2))
def sw = new StringWriter()
XmlUtil.serialize(dom, sw)
println sw.toString()
```

The actual result of my code is like this:

```
<root>
  <level1/>
</root>
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `appendNode()` always appends at the end of the document, so you do not need to specify the last node. In your example, since `l2` has to be added as a child to `l1` so using `leftShift` will be an easier option:

```
def root="<root/>"
def l1 = "<level1/>"
def l2 = "<level2/>"

def dom = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(root)

dom << ( new XmlSlurper().parseText( l1 ) << new XmlSlurper().parseText( l2 ) )

def sw = new StringWriter()
XmlUtil.serialize(dom, sw)
println sw.toString()
```

Is there any reason you cannot use like this:

```
dom.root {
    level1 {
        level2 { }
    }
}
```

Normally, it is done using MarkupBuilder as:

```
def swr = new StringWriter()
def markup = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(swr)
markup.root {
    level1 {
        level2 { }
    }
}


println swr
```

What is the intention here using appendNode?

Comment: This is the result use your code:<root>
  <level1/>
  <level2/>
</root>

Comment: @eric2323223 Yes, I did not realize that in the expected xml level2 should be a child of level1. See my update above with the use of `<<` you would get the expected result. Still can you explain why you do not prefer MarkupBuilder for this, just curious? :)

Comment: I need to create a table like xml, the row and column are dynamically generated.

Comment: Wait, can you give an actual example separate from the contrived one using level1 and level2, may be it can be achieved easily than we think. I will be glad to help if I can. However, did you try my updated answer?

Comment: Your code works now, Thanks. It may take some time to give you a better sample code, I am working on it.

Comment: Can you describe your thought? maybe it's easier than extract a proper example from my real code.

Comment: Using DSL as I have shown in case of MarkupBuilder can be easily customized in case the logic of creating xml is dynamic. Same dsl approach is good if XmlSlurper is used. I was forecasting an easier way to create an xml markup without parsing each piece every time.